# Use system Node.js installation per default with NVM present

Tags: node.js, zsh, nvm

I installed the latest Node.js via Homebrew, then installed nvm in case I need specific versions of Node.js. When NVM loads a non-system Node.js it adds about 800ms of launch time to a shell. Therefore I would like to not load a NVM installed Node.js version on launch.

This worked (see screenshot below) before I had any Node.js version installed with NVM.
However installing one Node.js version via NVM also set that version as default.

How can I load system per default?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a default Node version to be used in any new shell, use the alias 'default':

`nvm alias default system`